Make terraform asset
{
"module": "module.cmp1_test",
"mode": "managed",
"type": "netbox_device",
"name": "device",
"provider": "provider.netbox",
"instances": [
{
"schema_version": 0,
"attributes": {
"face": 0,
"id": "2828",
"name": "cmp1",
"position": 15,
"rack": "111",
"role": "cmp",
"serial": "",
"site": "example.site",
"status": "Planned",
"tenant": "VPC",
"type": "Generic-1U"
},
"private": "bnVsbA=="
}
]
}
{
"module": "module.cmp1_test",
"mode": "managed",
"type": "netbox_device",
"name": "device",
"provider": "provider.netbox",
"instances": [
{
"schema_version": 0,
"attributes": {
"face": 0,
"id": "2828",
"name": "cmp1",
"position": 15,
"rack": "111",
"role": "cmp",
"serial": "",
"site": "example.site",
"status": "Planned",
"tenant": "VPC",
"type": "Generic-1U"
}
